# What happens if I set transformer_weights to 0 for FeatureUnion?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

What happens if I set transformer_weights to 0 for FeatureUnion? I am wondering can I use this approach to opt out a set of features in GridSearchCV. In this way I can take advantage of the cross validation of GridSearchCV to test whether a feature improves prediction.

Also, any idea of how different models react to this transformer_weights change. I think MultinationalNB with smoothing may be used to test the idea of whether a set of feature is useful.

(Or any other thoughts on how to test the importance of features? My other thought is to do a feature selection, and see whether the 'feather been tested' are dropped by various feature selection methods. But on the other side, prediction performance of best estimator from GridSearchCV on the held out data set is an "ultimate" test, so I would still use this test instead of feature selection. )

Here is a example pipeline with FeatureUnion.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    # Use FeatureUnion to combine the features
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[
            # Pipeline for pulling features from the post's subject line
            ('subject', Pipeline([
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='subject')),
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=50)),
            ])),

            # Pipeline for standard bag-of-words model for body
            ('body_bow', Pipeline([
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='body')),
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                ('best', TruncatedSVD(n_components=50)),
            ])),
        ],

        # weight components in FeatureUnion
        transformer_weights={
            'body_bow': 1.0,
            'subject': 0.0,
        },
    )),

    ('svc', SVC(kernel='linear')),
])
```

A full example from Matt Terry can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html):

Answer (score 0):

It's simply constant multiplier of some transformer output. i.e. you can assume that by default this constant is 1 for each transformer, and your FeatureUnion will output:

```
numpy.hstack((body_bow_output_matrix*1.0, subject_output_matrix*0.0))
```

Read this [feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) also.